# How make this hover effect on click to button?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap

I need change image to click on button "Click here to change image with effect of hover" with the effect (I use [this liblary](https://github.com/robin-dela/hover-effect/blob/master/src/hover-effect.js) for effect) that is now on hover. And I do not need the effect to occur on the hover. How realize that?
I spread an example on my server, becouse jsfiddle do not support WebGl.

[See my example](http://samlpetask.000webhostapp.com/hover-effect/slide-effect.html)

My code:

```js
!function(f,l){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=l(require("three"),require("gsap/TweenMax")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["three","gsap/TweenMax"],l):f.hoverEffect=l(f.THREE,f.TweenMax)}(this,function(f,l){return l=l&&l.hasOwnProperty("default")?l.default:l,function(h){function F(){for(var f=arguments,l=0;l<arguments.length;l++)if(void 0!==f[l])return f[l]}console.log("%c Hover effect by Robin Delaporte: https://github.com/robin-dela/hover-effect ","color: #bada55; font-size: 0.8rem");var w=h.parent,L=h.displacementImage,M=h.image1,P=h.image2,U=F(h.intensity1,h.intensity,1),V=F(h.intensity2,h.intensity,1),C=F(h.angle,Math.PI/4),D=F(h.angle1,C),S=F(h.angle2,3*-C),W=F(h.speedIn,h.speed,1.6),_=F(h.speedOut,h.speed,1.2),z=F(h.hover,!0),q=F(h.easing,Expo.easeOut),G=F(h.video,!1);if(w)if(M&&P&&L){var A=new f.Scene,B=new f.OrthographicCamera(w.offsetWidth/-2,w.offsetWidth/2,w.offsetHeight/2,w.offsetHeight/-2,1,1e3);B.position.z=1;var k=new f.WebGLRenderer({antialias:!1,alpha:!0});k.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio),k.setClearColor(16777215,0),k.setSize(w.offsetWidth,w.offsetHeight),w.appendChild(k.domElement);var J=function(){k.render(A,B)},K=new f.TextureLoader;K.crossOrigin="";var N=K.load(L,J);if(N.wrapS=N.wrapT=f.RepeatWrapping,G){var Q=function(){requestAnimationFrame(Q),k.render(A,B)};Q(),(G=document.createElement("video")).autoplay=!0,G.loop=!0,G.src=M,G.load();var X=document.createElement("video");X.autoplay=!0,X.loop=!0,X.src=P,X.load();var Y=new f.VideoTexture(G),Z=new f.VideoTexture(X);Y.magFilter=Z.magFilter=f.LinearFilter,Y.minFilter=Z.minFilter=f.LinearFilter,X.addEventListener("loadeddata",function(){X.play(),(Z=new f.VideoTexture(X)).magFilter=f.LinearFilter,Z.minFilter=f.LinearFilter,$.uniforms.texture2.value=Z},!1),G.addEventListener("loadeddata",function(){G.play(),(Y=new f.VideoTexture(G)).magFilter=f.LinearFilter,Y.minFilter=f.LinearFilter,$.uniforms.texture1.value=Y},!1)}else Y=K.load(M,J),Z=K.load(P,J),Y.magFilter=Z.magFilter=f.LinearFilter,Y.minFilter=Z.minFilter=f.LinearFilter;var $=new f.ShaderMaterial({uniforms:{intensity1:{type:"f",value:U},intensity2:{type:"f",value:V},dispFactor:{type:"f",value:0},angle1:{type:"f",value:D},angle2:{type:"f",value:S},texture1:{type:"t",value:Y},texture2:{type:"t",value:Z},disp:{type:"t",value:N}},vertexShader:"\nvarying vec2 vUv;\nvoid main() {\n  vUv = uv;\n  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );\n}\n",fragmentShader:"\nvarying vec2 vUv;\n\nuniform float dispFactor;\nuniform sampler2D disp;\n\nuniform sampler2D texture1;\nuniform sampler2D texture2;\nuniform float angle1;\nuniform float angle2;\nuniform float intensity1;\nuniform float intensity2;\n\nmat2 getRotM(float angle) {\n  float s = sin(angle);\n  float c = cos(angle);\n  return mat2(c, -s, s, c);\n}\n\nvoid main() {\n  vec4 disp = texture2D(disp, vUv);\n  vec2 dispVec = vec2(disp.r, disp.g);\n  vec2 distortedPosition1 = vUv + getRotM(angle1) * dispVec * intensity1 * dispFactor;\n  vec2 distortedPosition2 = vUv + getRotM(angle2) * dispVec * intensity2 * (1.0 - dispFactor);\n  vec4 _texture1 = texture2D(texture1, distortedPosition1);\n  vec4 _texture2 = texture2D(texture2, distortedPosition2);\n  gl_FragColor = mix(_texture1, _texture2, dispFactor);\n}\n",transparent:!0,opacity:1}),y=new f.PlaneBufferGeometry(w.offsetWidth,w.offsetHeight,1),b=new f.Mesh(y,$);A.add(b),z&&(w.addEventListener("mouseenter",j),w.addEventListener("touchstart",j),w.addEventListener("mouseleave",O),w.addEventListener("touchend",O)),window.addEventListener("resize",function(f){k.setSize(w.offsetWidth,w.offsetHeight)}),this.next=j,this.previous=O}else console.warn("One or more images are missing");else console.warn("Parent missing");function j(){l.to($.uniforms.dispFactor,W,{value:1,ease:q,onUpdate:J,onComplete:J})}function O(){l.to($.uniforms.dispFactor,_,{value:0,ease:q,onUpdate:J,onComplete:J})}}});
//# sourceMappingURL=hover-effect.umd.js.map

new hoverEffect({
 parent: document.querySelector('.distortion'),
 intensity: 0.3,
 image1: 'https://tympanus.net/Development/DistortionHoverEffect/img/Img22.jpg',
 image2: 'https://tympanus.net/Development/DistortionHoverEffect/img/Img21.jpg',
 displacementImage: 'https://tympanus.net/Development/DistortionHoverEffect/img/displacement/8.jpg'
});
```

```css
.landing {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 height: 100vh;
}

.distortion {
 width: 640px;
 height: 920px;
 align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/107/three.min.js"></script>

<div class="landing">
  <div class="intro">
      <h2>Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
        <p>
          <button>Click here to change image with effect of hover</button>
        </p>
  </div>
 <div class="distortion"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The statement that "jsfiddle does not support WebGL" is wrong. WebGL apps run absolutely fine with jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a new variable by adding `var clickBtn = opts.clickBtn;` in [the variables](https://github.com/robin-dela/hover-effect/blob/master/src/hover-effect.js#L56).

Then change

```
if (userHover) {
    parent.addEventListener('mouseenter', transitionIn);
    parent.addEventListener('touchstart', transitionIn);
    parent.addEventListener('mouseleave', transitionOut);
    parent.addEventListener('touchend', transitionOut);
}
```

to

```
if (userHover) {
    clickBtn.addEventListener('click', transitionIn);
}
```

in [the event listeners](https://github.com/robin-dela/hover-effect/blob/master/src/hover-effect.js#L230).

Lastly you'd need to change the instantiation to:

```
new hoverEffect({
    parent: document.querySelector('.distortion'),
    clickBtn: document.querySelector('button'),
    intensity: 0.3,
    image1: 'https://tympanus.net/Development/DistortionHoverEffect/img/Img22.jpg',
    image2: 'https://tympanus.net/Development/DistortionHoverEffect/img/Img21.jpg',
    displacementImage: 'https://tympanus.net/Development/DistortionHoverEffect/img/displacement/8.jpg'
});
```

To have it toggle between the two, you should create a boolean to keep track of the state, making it `true` in the `transitionIn` function and `false` in the `transitionOut` function. Then you can check which state it is and call the appropriate function on click.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's great! But I did not understand the implementation with toogle. I declare variable "changeState" and checked status in functions. How I use this variable further? Modeled here: https://jsfiddle.net/zrw61s5o/

Comment: Check out the `toggleChange` function I added [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0d3mfL82/) :)